# Is it possible to connect to IRC from a Cordova Application

Tags: php, cordova, websocket

I have looked into all kinds of posts but none seem to come to an answer/conclusion.

Is it possible? If so what is the right direction to take?

Comment: why would you choose a Cordova Application for that ?

Comment: It's a feature within a cordova application i have built.

Comment: No, not directly. You would have to have a node.js server running to facilitate the connection. Then you could create a side API for your app the connect to and have the node server act as a relay.

Comment: which platform you use? android or iOS?

Comment: Mainly Android at the moment, ideally i'd like it to function on IoS also